# Como executar criar banco de dados mysql utilizando shell script se o nome da base possui "-"

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, linux, shell, shell-script

No servidor existem algumas bases de dados com o nome `modelo-submodelo`
(esse é o nome da base de dados, criaram com "-" mesmo).

Quando executo um comando como:

```
mysqldump -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" modelo-submodelo --compress=TRUE > $TEMP/$DBTEMPNAME
```

funciona normalmente. No entanto, se eu tenho que criar a base novamente utilizando linha de comando:

```
mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" -e "create database modelo-submodelo;"
```

retorna o erro, devido ao "-":

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '-submodelo' at line 1

Como devo montar esse comando para que não de o erro e crie a base de dados corretamente?

Comment: Tente "create database \"modelo-submodelo\";"

Comment: Experimente também com o acento grave, `mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" -e "create database \`modelo-submodelo\`;"`

Comment: @lazyFox funcionou, dentro do script tive de colocar `mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" -e "create database \`modelo-submodelo\`;"` muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se facilmente incluir o hífen no comando fazendo uso do acento grave, segue exemplo:

```
mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" -e "create database `modelo-submodelo`;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que necessitar utilizar caracteres especiais como pate do conteúdo de parâmetros de linha de comando (bash), utilize aspas (simples ou duplas) em torno de todo o valor do parâmetro. Você pode ainda intercalá-las. Lembrando que aspas duplas sujeitam o conteúdo a ser expandido (quando couber) enquanto que as aspas simples não.

No seu caso, o comando de criação de tabela é executado pelo cliente mysql (através da opção "-e"), e não pelo shell, sujeitando o comando passado às regras do aplicativo. Então sua linha de comando deve ficar assim:

mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" -e "create database `modelo-submodelo`;"